# Complicated MYSql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table called 'ebaylinked' what im trying to do is create a trigger that will check if the field 'Processed?' is 1
if it is I want it to to use the field called 'ebay_ID' and find the corresponding column on the table 'product' the field on the products table is
'eBay_ID' when it finds it i want it to to use the field 'QuantitySold' from the 'ebaylinked' table and subtract the int value from the 'product_stock'
field in the 'products' table then I want it to change processed to 0 so that it can't do it again.

I'm confused with how to even start it as it's quite a complicated trigger if anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreicate it,
its sending me mad at the moment...

```
UPDATE database.product.product_stock
SET product.product_stock=product.product_stock-ebaylinked.QuantitySold,product.Processed? = 0
FROM
database.ebaylinked,
WHERE
database.product.eBay_ID database.ebaylinked.ebay_ID
```

Comment: Post what you've got so far and we'll try to help you head in the right direction.

Comment: try to add some structure and sample data also. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Comment: Are you sure that you need a trigger and not a stored procedure?

Comment: I'm very new to this I've had an attempt but i think im on the wrong lines adding it to question

Comment: Have no idea if I can use a minus in it to takeaway one field from another, don't know if I can set value as zero like that, and don't know how to approach the 'only carry it out if Processed is set to 1...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but your question is quite hard to understand. As far as I can tell you simply want to update the product quantity field at some point and subtract the number of ebay sales.

This is the query I've come up just to update the product_stock field:

```
UPDATE
    product
    JOIN TABLE ebaylinked ON
        ebaylinked.eBay_ID = product.eBay_ID
SET
    product.product_stock = product.product_stock - ebaylinked.QuantitySold
WHERE
    product.`Processed?` = 1
```

I'm not sure if these field names are what you have for your table, perhaps you could post the table schemas?

As for how to trigger this update, you need to give us some more details such as when it should occur.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple multi-table update statement:

```
UPDATE product p
INNER JOIN ebaylinked e ON e.eBay_ID = p.eBay_ID
SET p.product_stock = p.product_stock - e.QuantitySold, p.processed=0
WHERE
p.processed = 1
```

You can use the above statement in a trigger with slight modifications.

Comment: I have added it with update after (using phpmyadmin) went on but doesn't make any changes to database having a mess around to see if i can get it working